Location to store database that will not sync with the OS sync framework
My UWP app developed in MAUI is using an SQLite database. According to the documentation I should use the AppDataDirectory for this. The problem lies in this statement:

These files are backed up with the operating system syncing framework.

This database will store sensitive data (it is encrypted) and should not get synced. So how do I prevent files from being synced to the cloud by the OS? Are there permissions I can set on files? Or is there a more secure place to store the database?

Maui doesn't generate UWP apps,and maui (on Windows) uses Windows App SDK / WinUI .
